# Does Microsoft Graph API require Microsoft 365 subscription to work with Microsoft To Do?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Does Microsoft Graph API require Microsoft 365 subscription to work with Microsoft To Do task list? I understand a typical outlook.com account comes with a To Do task list for free.

Comment: I don't think you need subscription. Try it in [graph explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) and see if it works

Comment: Did it helped you?

Comment: If my answer is helpful please accept it so that it could be helpful to others. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead and simply test it on [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge). According to the overview page of Microsoft Graph To-Do API there is no sign that we need a license.

I have tried testing it by disabling the To-Do Plan 3 of my Microsoft 365 subscription, and it still worked for me.

[image]

[image]